# How do you convert a JQuery element into a string and access it using JavaScript's indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<head>
    <meta property="article:section" content="Pop or Not" />
</head>
```

JS

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

          var metaSection $("meta[property='article:section']").attr("content");


          if (metaSection.indexOf('Pop or Not') >= 0){
              alert ('The is Pop Page!');
          }

  });  
</script>
```

The problem is that I think I need to that in order to use the variable I've defined I need to convert it into a string. Would definitely like some input.

Comment: What does `console.log(metaSection);` give you?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Please add a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it's hard to answer by anything other than guessing

Comment: P.S. You're missing a `=` and `;`.

Comment: P.P.S. Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/a7rd53p3/

Comment: @RocketHazmat It gives me the following `"Uncaught ReferenceError: metaSection is not definedat <anonymous>:1:13"`  Even though I defined it

Comment: You are declaring `metaSection` but, as @RocketHazmat said, you are missing the equal sign (`=`) to assign a value to it as well as the semi-colon (`;`) at the end

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I updated my code added an "=" to my variable and colon at the end

Comment: @ochi I updated my code. Sorry, I left out the complete text from attribute "content" The complete text is **Pop or Not** which contains spaces. I think this is the problem

Comment: @Mariton: Your *real* code has `var metaSection = ...`, right?

Comment: The spaces is not the issue, however. It's the lack of equal sign (I am not sure I can saying in a different way) look at the answer below - it works with either `Pop` or `Pop or Not` as the content

Comment: @RocketHazmat  You were right. I retested and it my code was not working do to the `=` and `;` being missing. Works great now!

Comment: @ochi Yes you are right about this. I just checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if HTML is ok

```js
var metaSection = $("meta[property='article:section']").attr("content");

if (metaSection.indexOf('Pop') >= 0) {
  alert('The is Pop Page!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta property="article:section" content="Pop" />
</head>
```

Comment: @ochi This helped out

Comment: @ochi Actually, I didn't ignore your comments at all. I replied back to all of them (including yours) while testing at the same time. I already mentioned that I realized that  RocketHazmat and you were correct that `=` and `;` were missing and I confirmed that space was not an issue. I even upvoted your comment. I didn't jump too conclusions because I read each of the comments and got my code to work, So I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @ochi  I am sorry that you were quick to get frustrated but you should reread my comments. I think you're the one that jumped to conclusions on this one. But anyway I appreciate your help. Because it helped my code.

Comment: @Mariton my apologies, I got frustrated. I will remove my comments.  There is no problem. Again, welcome to SO